# Estimate range of solution of a initial value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

**Question:** Show that the solution to the initial value problem $$x'=x^2+cos(t^2)$$ $$x(0)=0$$ is defined for $\lvert t \rvert\le\frac{1}{2}$ and satisfies there $\lvert x(t) \rvert\le1$.

**My Attempt:** Let $f(t,x)=x^2+cos(t^2)$, then $x'=f(x,t)$.

The Lipschitz condition:
$$\lvert \frac{f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)}{x_1-x_2}\rvert=\lvert \frac{x_1^2-x_2^2}{x_1-x_2}\rvert=\lvert x_1+x_2\rvert$$

Because $x(0)=0$ and $x'>0$ for  $\lvert t \rvert\le\frac{1}{2}$, $$x(t)>0$$
However, I could not prove the Lipschitz condition that $\lvert \frac{f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)}{x_1-x_2}\rvert$ is bounded. For example, suppose $x$ takes the limit of infinity, $$\lvert \frac{f(t,x_1)-f(t,x_2)}{x_1-x_2}\rvert=\lvert x_1+x_2\rvert=\infty$$

I do not know how to proceed from here. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(t,x)$ is locally Lipschitz in $x$, but not globally. This is enough to guarantee existence and uniqueness on some interval $[0,T)$ with $T>0$ (possibly $\infty$.)

On any interval where the solution is defined we have
$$
x'\le x^2+1.
$$
Integrate this inequality to obtain un upper bound on $x$.